# Using Micronaut CLI to create app, controller

Tags: java, micronaut

Micronaut CLI is very useful while creating the application, however the command to create a controller is not present in the CLI.

```
Micronaut Version: 2.0.3
```

From the micronaut documentation we have a command for profile https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.0.M3/guide/index.html#cli

```
$ mn profile-info service
Profile: service
------------------
The service profile

Provided Commands:
--------------------
  create-bean              Creates a singleton bean
  create-client            Creates a client interface
  create-controller        Creates a controller and associated test
  create-job               Creates a job with scheduled method
  create-test              Creates a simple test for the project's testing framework
  create-websocket-client  Creates a Websocket client
  create-websocket-server  Creates a Websocket server
  help                     Prints help information for a specific command


Provided Features:
------------------
...
```

When I run the command `mn profile-info service` I get an error as

[image]

I have only below options

[image]

I am trying to create a controller from the cli

Comment: I need to be in the root of the project to get those options

Answer (score 0):

Profiles were only in Micronaut version 1.x. So profile related commands like `mn profile-info service` are not available in Micronaut version 2.x.

When you create the project end enter the project directory you can use these additional `mn` commands:

- `feature-diff` - Produces the diff of an original project with an original project with additional features.
- `create-job` - Creates a job with scheduled method
- `create-client` - Creates a client interface
- `create-controller` - Creates a controller and associated test
- `create-test` - Creates a simple test for the project's testing framework
- `create-bean` - Creates a singleton bean
- `create-websocket-client` - Creates a Websocket client
- `create-websocket-server` - Creates a Websocket server

And you can also see more description of the command when you call it with `-h` option. For example:

```
$ mn create-controller -h
Usage: mn create-controller [-fhvVx] CONTROLLER-NAME
Creates a controller and associated test
      CONTROLLER-NAME   The name of the controller to create
  -f, --force           Whether to overwrite existing files
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
  -v, --verbose         Create verbose output.
  -V, --version         Print version information and exit.
  -x, --stacktrace      Show full stack trace when exceptions occur.
```